# Does the Dask library for Python offer SVD yet?

Tags: dask

The Dask FAQ mentions singular value decomposition (SVD), http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/faq.html. But I don't see SVD in the API. I've installed 0.8.0, the latest version of PyPi.

Thanks,
Carl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an SVD algorithm for dask arrays.  See the `dask.array.linalg` module.